# How can I show this directional derivatives and gradient vector relation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can I show that?

If $f_{(\vec{u})}(\vec{x}) = f_{(-\vec{u})}(\vec{x})$ for all $\vec{u}$, then $\nabla f(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$. Recall that if $v \in \Bbb R^n$ then we show that whenever $f$ is differentiable at $p \in \Bbb R^n$ then it possess every directional derivatives at $p$ and the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v$ is $\nabla f(p) \cdot v$.

Now, for every $v$ we have $D_v f(p) = D_{-v} f(p)$, in that case we have

$$\nabla f(p)\cdot v = \nabla f(p) \cdot (-v),$$

and in that case, since dot products are bilinear, this is the same as:

$$\nabla f(p) \cdot v = - \nabla f(p) \cdot v,$$

which implies that $\nabla f(p) \cdot v + \nabla f(p) \cdot v = 0$ and this obviously implies that $\nabla f(p) \cdot v = 0$.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:${\vec D_{\vec{u}}f(\vec{x})}= \nabla f(\vec{x}).{\vec{u}}$

Comment: I'm still stuck. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user78723: you can always try to use components. Say $\nabla f = a \vec{i} + b \vec{j} + c \vec{k}$. How can you compute $a$ as a directional derivative?